# Declare closure into a loop (in the context of performance)

Tags: go, closures

Is there a difference (in the context of performance) between the three implementations below?:

---

```
mustGetSpeed := func() string {
    ...
    return speed
}

for _, item := range items {
    speed, err := strconv.Atoi(mustGetSpeed())
    ...
}
```

---

```
for _, item := range items {
    mustGetSpeed := func() string {
        ...
        return speed
    }
    speed, err := strconv.Atoi(mustGetSpeed())
    ...
}
```

---

```
for _, item := range items {
    speed, err := strconv.Atoi(func() string {
        ...
        return speed
    }())
    ...
}
```

Is it a mistake (in the context of performance) declares closure into a loop?

Comment: Just a note, `item` in your loop is not the actual item object but the index.

Comment: I doubt the last two differ -- I think the only difference is whether the function value goes into an unnamed temporary space or a variable named `mustGetSpeed`. I'm not *entirely* sure whether manually hoisting the decl up out of the loop helps out the compiler, especially if the closure is capturing local variables from its context. That's at least worth testing.

Comment: I would guess they are all optimized into very similar code. The thing is, if there was overhead to using your closure in the loop then their usefulness would be greatly diminished. I'd prove that theory but don't really have the time to write a test program.

Comment: Just my unsound thought is that the first one should be the fastest. It creates the function only once, whereas the second that creates it in a loop would be the slowest

Answer (score 1):

You are speculating about a performance question. Don't do that. Get some facts. Run some benchmarks. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "strconv"
    "testing"
)

const sound = "1236" // speed of sound 1,236 kilometres per hour

var items = make([]int, 1024)

func BenchmarkClosure1(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        mustGetSpeed := func() string {
            speed := sound
            // ...
            return speed
        }
        for _, item := range items {
            speed, err := strconv.Atoi(mustGetSpeed())
            // ...
            _, _, _ = item, speed, err
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkClosure2(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for _, item := range items {
            mustGetSpeed := func() string {
                speed := sound
                // ...
                return speed
            }
            speed, err := strconv.Atoi(mustGetSpeed())
            // ...
            _, _, _ = item, speed, err
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkClosure3(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for _, item := range items {
            speed, err := strconv.Atoi(func() string {
                speed := sound
                // ...
                return speed
            }())
            // ...
            _, _, _ = item, speed, err
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
BenchmarkClosure1      10000        156031 ns/op
BenchmarkClosure2      10000        156955 ns/op
BenchmarkClosure3      10000        152546 ns/op
```

Comment: Interestingly (to me at least), if the call to `strconv.Atoi` (which takes 90+% of the time) is removed so that just the closure/function is called then I appear to consistently get Closure1 slower-than Closure2 slower-than Closure3 (with slice sizes from 64 to 64k). I haven't looked at the assembly output. The times are close enough that unless this was in a very time critical section of code it just doesn't matter.